# Is there a way to detect a bounced Digital Experience invitation email?

Tags: community, email, user-management, digital-experience

It appears that Digital Experience invitation emails do not produce an [EmailMessage](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_emailmessage.htm) record that includes an `IsBounced` field.

Is there any way to detect bounced invitations?